# How can I disable Google Voice Commands on an Android phone?

Tags: google-voice, google-voice-actions

I prefer not root my phone, but I'd be willing to, if it's necessary.

Google Voice keeps popping-up *Search* and *Voice Dialer* randomly (about twice a minute). They enter random commands into *Search bar* and I can't turn them off.  The problem might be caused by inexpensive headphones.

I'd like to just completely remove the software from my phone.  If I can't do that, I'd like to get them to stop randomly popping up.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how you can turn this off in most Android builds:

Look for an app called "Google Settings." By default, the icon will look like this:

[image]

From there, choose "Search & Now" → "Voice" → "'Ok Google' hotword detection" and turn that setting off.

If that doesn't apply to your phone's OS, you'll need to provide more info. If you are running the OS that came with the phone, provide the make and model. If it is rooted, provide the name and version of the custom ROM.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more on android 6.0 :( I turned of "Ok google detection" but I still get the microphone thing popping up all the time.

Answer (score 2):

I also think the voice recognition is a nuisance.  On my phone (running CyanogenMod) the only setting I found was "Settings", "Language & Input" -> "Voice Search" then disable "Ok Google" detection.  I think it was mishearing my saying "Ok Google" when it would pick up random voice commands.

Comment: I'm super frustrated because my child is able to do things on my phone that she can't actually spell. My solution was to do as you describe here, and also change the speech recognition language to Magyr.