# Nexus 5 Android 6.0 Voice dailer keeps popping up when headphones in

Tags: nexus-5, 6.0-marshmallow

A few days ago my phone has begun popping up voice dailer seemingly at random while I have headphones plugged into it.

I have gone into settings and attempted to disable everything I could find related to the voice dailer, but it still pops up.

It seems like I will be listening to music or a podcast, and then all of a sudden what I am listening to will be interrupted by a sound, and the voice dialer comes up.

Since I have shut off all permissions to my mic it now immediately stops and fortunately doesn't tell me to speak the name of who I am calling, but why its interrupting me at all is perplexing to me.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Plug your headphones into your phone. Then try pressing the buttons on your wire. Do any of those buttons cause the voice dialer to pop up?

Comment: I don't have any buttons on my headphones.

Comment: Possibly related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75226/how-can-i-disable-google-voice-commands-on-an-android-phone